# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel Property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

The `Customer` property is only used to link a new `Project` to the Customer, so I don't include this property in my Create view, which looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Project</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Project.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I post the form, the following method in my `ProjectsController` is triggered:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Project,Customer")] ProjectViewModel vm)
{
    var project = Mapper.Map<Project>(vm);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Create(project);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

This is where the unexpected behaviour occurs. Now, when I examine the `vm` property, the `Customer` property is `null`.

**The question**
How can I still keep the `Customer` property filled, while not using it in the view?

Comment: If you are not reading any customer property values from the user input, why not set that in your HttpPost action method as needed ? Are you intending to save a dummy customer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to persist your Customer data, then you need to set all the fields as hidden elements otherwise they will be lost in the redirect.

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Customer.Property1) ...etc...`

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't.  When data is posted back, the only data that is included is what is in the form on the HTML page.

Your best bet is to either use a session variable or look up the data again in the post handler, or alternatively, serialize the data to hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the **Customer** property is *never null* when initializing **ProjectViewModel**, you could add a constructor to your **ProjectViewModel** class initializing the **Customer** property to a `new Customer()` like so:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    // Constructor
    public ProjectViewModel()
    {
        Customer = new Customer();
    }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```